# Embedding manifest to exe file

Tags: c++, exe, manifest

I have a `.manifest` file which is linked with a `.exe` program file so that it asks for admin privileges when opened. Now it is a separate file called `program_name.exe.manifest` which is is the same folder as `program_name.exe`. Is there any way by which we can embed the manifest file into the `.exe` file so that it can be one single file instead of two.

BTW the program is created using C++

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Declare the manifest as a resource and then just build the resource object file and link it to your exe.

In your `resource.rc` file, define your manifest resource like so:

```
IDR_RT_MANIFEST1        RT_MANIFEST            "program_name.exe.manifest"
```

In your `resource.h` file declare it with the value 1

```
#define IDR_RT_MANIFEST1    1
```

Build the resource file with windres: `windres resource.rc -o resource.o`

Link the resource when building your project: `-l resource.o`

.........................................................................

**If your're using Visual Studio** you don't need to build it explicitly, but there are 2 options which should be set beforehand:

1) `Project > Project_Name Properties > Configuration Properties > Linker > Manifest File -> Generate Manifest` set to `No`

2) `Project > Project_Name Properties > Configuration Properties > Manifest Tool > Embed Manifest` set to `Yes`

Also add your manifest file to your project as existing item.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows CL, like powershell, try

`program_name.exe –manifest program_name.exe.manifest -outputresource:program_name.exe;1`

That should do the trick.

Comment: **C:\WINDOWS\system32>main.exe -manifest main.exe.manifest -outputsource:main.exe;1**
'main.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: You can either try running the command from the folder that has the .exe in it or you can follow this thread on changing your environment variables to make the program runnable from any folder http://stackoverflow.com/a/8939956/8021378