# Mingw produces x86 program which only successfully runs as Administrator- x64 and VS(x86 and x64) versions fine

Tags: c, windows, winapi, x86, mingw-w64

I was taking a look at this Github project: https://github.com/LloydLabs/delete-self-poc

This project uses the SetFileInformationByHandle API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfileinformationbyhandle) in a somewhat creative way to allow the deletion from disk of a locked file.  I am attempting to implement this as part of a larger program, however I have ran into an issue when compiling for x86.  I use mingw-w64 on a debian machine to compile my program and when doing compatibility checks for x86, I found a very strange issue.

```
#include "main.h"

static
HANDLE
ds_open_handle(
    PWCHAR pwPath
)
{
    return CreateFileW(pwPath, DELETE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
}

static
BOOL
ds_rename_handle(
    HANDLE hHandle
)
{
    FILE_RENAME_INFO fRename;
    RtlSecureZeroMemory(&fRename, sizeof(fRename));

    // set our FileNameLength and FileName to DS_STREAM_RENAME
    LPWSTR lpwStream = DS_STREAM_RENAME;
    fRename.FileNameLength = sizeof(lpwStream);
    RtlCopyMemory(fRename.FileName, lpwStream, sizeof(lpwStream));

    return SetFileInformationByHandle(hHandle, FileRenameInfo, &fRename, sizeof(fRename) + sizeof(lpwStream));
}

static
BOOL 
ds_deposite_handle(
    HANDLE hHandle
)
{
    // set FILE_DISPOSITION_INFO::DeleteFile to TRUE
    FILE_DISPOSITION_INFO fDelete;
    RtlSecureZeroMemory(&fDelete, sizeof(fDelete));

    fDelete.DeleteFile = TRUE;

    return SetFileInformationByHandle(hHandle, FileDispositionInfo, &fDelete, sizeof(fDelete));
}

int
main(
    int argc,
    char** argv
)
{
    WCHAR wcPath[MAX_PATH + 1];
    RtlSecureZeroMemory(wcPath, sizeof(wcPath));

    // get the path to the current running process ctx
    if (GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, wcPath, MAX_PATH) == 0)
    {
        DS_DEBUG_LOG(L"failed to get the current module handle");
        return 0;
    }

    HANDLE hCurrent = ds_open_handle(wcPath);
    if (hCurrent == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        DS_DEBUG_LOG(L"failed to acquire handle to current running process");
        return 0;
    }

    // rename the associated HANDLE's file name
    DS_DEBUG_LOG(L"attempting to rename file name");
    if (!ds_rename_handle(hCurrent))
    {
        DS_DEBUG_LOG(L"failed to rename to stream");
        return 0;
    }

    DS_DEBUG_LOG(L"successfully renamed file primary :$DATA ADS to specified stream, closing initial handle");
    CloseHandle(hCurrent);

    // open another handle, trigger deletion on close
    hCurrent = ds_open_handle(wcPath);
    if (hCurrent == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        DS_DEBUG_LOG(L"failed to reopen current module");
        return 0;
    }

    if (!ds_deposite_handle(hCurrent))
    {
        DS_DEBUG_LOG(L"failed to set delete deposition");
        return 0;
    }

    // trigger the deletion deposition on hCurrent
    DS_DEBUG_LOG(L"closing handle to trigger deletion deposition");
    CloseHandle(hCurrent);

    // verify we've been deleted
    if (PathFileExistsW(wcPath))
    {
        DS_DEBUG_LOG(L"failed to delete copy, file still exists");
        return 0;
    }

    DS_DEBUG_LOG(L"successfully deleted self from disk");
    return 1;
}
```

When compiling the base code found in the linked repository (and shown above) as x86, attempting to run the program fails at the SetFileInformationByHandle call in the ds_rename_handle function. Calling GetLastError() returns 123:

```
ERROR_INVALID_NAME

123 (0x7B)

The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

The very bizarre part is that the program succeeds when ran from an Administrator prompt.  Even stranger, compiling the same code for x64 works both in a normal and an Administrator prompt.

As a sanity check I copied the code verbatim over to VS2019 and compiled there, and the resulting x86 program was able to run without Administrator privileges.

The only changes to the source code made on the debian system were made in the header file:

```
#pragma once

#pragma comment(lib, "Shlwapi.lib")

#include <Windows.h>
#include <shlwapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DS_STREAM_RENAME L":wtfbbq"
#define DS_DEBUG_LOG(msg) wprintf(L"[LOG] - %s\n", msg)
```

Where <Windows.h> was changed to <windows.h> and the DS_DEBUG_LOG line changed to %ls so that the entire log message would print.

The GCC command used to compile for x86 was:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc main.c -o delete32.exe -s -DUNICODE -Os -lshlwapi
```

I have tried removing all switches and compiling and it still fails.

As a note, the shlwapi library is only required for the very last call in main(), PathFileExistsW.  I have commented out that portion and removed shlwapi from imports and from the gcc command to no effect.

The x64 gcc command which succeeded was:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc main.c -o delete32.exe -s -DUNICODE -Os -lshlwapi
```

In the issues tab of the github repo there are some mentions of errors in the code which I have looked at separately.  However I would desperately like to know why mingw is causing an issue with the 32 bit version of this program.  Unfortunately "just compile with VS" isn't an option, as I use a program to generate and compile the program that this bit of code will be part of on my linux machine.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: `RtlCopyMemory(fRename.FileName, lpwStream, sizeof(lpwStream));` is wrong in every way possible, surprised it works at all.

Comment: @CherryDT Thanks for the suggestion.  I am looking into doing that and learning about the joys (and headaches) of creating a .lib in VS and then getting it to work in GCC on linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RtlCopyMemory(fRename.FileName, lpwStream, sizeof(lpwStream));` writes 4 or 8 bytes into a 2 byte buffer! Who knows where the remaining bytes are going, the program behavior is probably undefined.

The concept of deleting a running exe like this might work but the code indicates that the author does not have a full understanding of Windows and C. You are better off rewriting it from scratch...

Edit:

After playing with your uploaded files I can with confidence say that it is the lack of a application manifest that causes it to fail when it is not elevated. Your vc file has a requestedExecutionLevel element which gives it Vista operating system context. If you remove the manifest resource in the vc exe it stops working. If you add a manifest to the mingw exe it starts working.

Comment: Understood, as I mentioned I am aware of the issues in the code and have another individual working on a better rewrite.  Interestingly, the first swing at solving the memory issues (which successfully wrote the full :wtfbbq into the fRename.FileName) resulted in an error 6: invalid handle From the SetFileInformationByHandle call.  Strange considering the handle that is passed to that function wasn't modified at all during this re-write.

Comment: @Octoberfest7 *Strange considering the handle that is passed to that function wasn't modified at all during this re-write*  How do you know?  The call to `RtlCopyMemory(fRename.FileName, lpwStream, sizeof(lpwStream));` overwrites memory - do you know what it stomped on?

Comment: Understood.  After a reworking of the code, we got it to function without overwriting/violating memory.  The issue persists however regarding the x86 non-admin version failing when compiled via mingw.  We attempted the static library as suggested by another poster, however were unable to make this work.  In reality our target architecture for this program is x64, having it work for x86 was really more of a legacy/"nice to have" so we might just bite the bullet and not have it.

Comment: @Anders I uploaded a mingw_x64 version to that github repo; I had another person look at it and they said it does NOT have a manifest file either; so apparently the x86 program requires a manifest to work however the x64 does not? So strange considering you can drop both on a single x64 machine and observe the behaviour that we are seeing here

Comment: @RbMm tagging you here as well for visibility of my above comment

Comment: 64-bit files do not have the same compatibility things applied to them. 32-bit has fixes for things going all the way back to Win95. Only 2003/"XPx64" had 64-bit before Vista and it was not very popular.

Comment: @Anders So is it that only certain API calls require the manifest file? I use a ton of other Win32API's (and NTAPI's) in my main program and it successfully compiles and runs as x86.  I just got unlucky in this instance? This must be a known problem elsewhere and we just failed to link the dots until now.  I will be attempting to create a manifest file and add it to my executable via mingw, hopefully it isn't too difficult.

Comment: Just to test it you can just write it as a text file and save it as "mingw_x86.exe.manifest". You can even copy the content from the vc file, starts with `<?xml` and ends with `</assembly>`. There are various APIs that change based on the manifest, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/win7appqual/compatibility---application-manifest# etc.

Comment: @Anders I am trying to manually add the manifest from the VS version following the guide I found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44030618/embedding-manifest-to-exe-file. I was sucessfully able to compile it all, however on run time I ran into the same issue.  I added this exe to the github (mingw_code folder) if you have time to check it out and see what looks like compared to the VS one

Comment: yes, you are correct. error inside *luafv.sys* (this is callback from *fltmgr.sys*) .the `LuafvPreSetInformation` called on rename. here called `LuafvQueryVirtualizationCaller` - this api check caller token for *TokenVirtualizationEnabled* and if yes - `LuafvPerformRename` called - here if name begin with **:** - `STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_INVALID` returned. from another side *TokenVirtualizationEnabled* return true if process not elevated and have no manifest

Comment: @Octoberfest7 - you use wrong manifest. must be https://pastebin.com/WsLJDbVj and **main** - wrong resource id - must be **1** but you use `IDR_RT_MANIFEST1` - system simply not view your manifest

Comment: @Anders Thank you for your work on this issue, with the guidance provided here we were able to successfully add a manifest to the x86 mingw program and get it to run.  I would upvote/provide rep for you but my account is too new.

Comment: @RbMm Thank you for your work on this issue, with the guidance provided here we were able to successfully add a manifest to the x86 mingw program and get it to run. I would upvote/provide rep for you but my account is too new.

Answer (score 1):

the `ds_rename_handle` function is wrong implemented.

the FILE_RENAME_INFO is **variable** size structure.

as result declaration

```
FILE_RENAME_INFO fRename;
```

almost always wrong (it will ok only if **FileName** containing 1 or 2 symbols)

really we need first calculate `FileNameLength` and then allocate `PFILE_RENAME_INFO`  based on this
as example:

```
ULONG FileNameLength = (ULONG)wcslen(DS_STREAM_RENAME) * sizeof(WCHAR);

ULONG dwBufferSize = FIELD_OFFSET(FILE_RENAME_INFO, FileName) + FileNameLength;

PFILE_RENAME_INFORMATION fRename = (PFILE_RENAME_INFORMATION)alloca(dwBufferSize);
```

so complete code for `ds_rename_handle` can be next:

```
ULONG ds_rename_handle(HANDLE hHandle, PCWSTR DS_STREAM_RENAME)
{
    ULONG FileNameLength = (ULONG)wcslen(DS_STREAM_RENAME) * sizeof(WCHAR);
    
    ULONG dwBufferSize = FIELD_OFFSET(FILE_RENAME_INFO, FileName) + FileNameLength;
    
    PFILE_RENAME_INFO fRename = (PFILE_RENAME_INFO)alloca(dwBufferSize);
    
    fRename->ReplaceIfExists = TRUE;
    fRename->RootDirectory = 0;
    fRename->FileNameLength = FileNameLength;
    memcpy(fRename->FileName, DS_STREAM_RENAME, FileNameLength);

    return SetFileInformationByHandle(hHandle, FileRenameInfo, 
        fRename, dwBufferSize) ? NOERROR : GetLastError();
}
```

but documentation of [`FILE_RENAME_INFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/ns-winbase-file_rename_info) is very bad. unclear - in what form - full pathname, file name or a relative pathname - must be **FileName** ?!

from my research - it must be full pathname only (not  file name) or begin with a colon **:** ( The new name for the stream )

much more better use [NtSetInformationFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntsetinformationfile) with `FileRenameInformation`

compare description of [`FILE_RENAME_INFORMATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/ns-ntifs-_file_rename_information) structure with [`FILE_RENAME_INFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/ns-winbase-file_rename_info) !

here exist detailed description - in what form **FileName** it should be.

so i always use

```
NTSTATUS ds_rename_handle_nt(HANDLE hHandle, PCWSTR DS_STREAM_RENAME)
{
    ULONG FileNameLength = (ULONG)wcslen(DS_STREAM_RENAME) * sizeof(WCHAR);

    ULONG dwBufferSize = FIELD_OFFSET(FILE_RENAME_INFO, FileName) + FileNameLength;

    PFILE_RENAME_INFORMATION fRename = (PFILE_RENAME_INFORMATION)alloca(dwBufferSize);

    fRename->ReplaceIfExists = TRUE;
    fRename->RootDirectory = 0;
    fRename->FileNameLength = FileNameLength;
    memcpy(fRename->FileName, DS_STREAM_RENAME, FileNameLength);

    IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb;
    return NtSetInformationFile(
        hHandle, &iosb, fRename, dwBufferSize, FileRenameInformation);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your post! The code samples you provided were very helpful and I am sure will be helpful to others in the future who are looking into this API/structs.

We tried your NT function however when compiling for x86 via MingW we are getting error 0xC0000033- STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_INVALID. Compiling for x64 via MingW works just fine.

Beyond the issues with the code which you and others have addressed (and we have corrected), this really seems to be an issue with MingW for some reason.

Comment: As an aside, I have come accross many of your comments and replies to users' issues on StackOverflow that have been very helpful to me (most recently concerning CreateProcessAsUser and spawning a session 0 process from a user session) so thank you for all of your work here

Comment: @Octoberfest7 - *`0xC0000033` - STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_INVALID* this mean that you use full path name for file and it not in nt-form. what exactly name you use ? i guess this is win32 form. also `FILE_RENAME_INFORMATION` accept file name or a relative pathname.

Comment: The name being passed in to FileName is L":wtfbbq" from the header file in the main post. This is the DS_STREAM_RENAME define.  This github project is renaming the data primary data stream

Comment: How is it possible for VCx86 to work but MinGWx86 to fail? Can you check the NtSetInformationFile call in a debugger? Compare the parameters and the data in the rename buffer...

Comment: @Octoberfest7 with  L":wtfbbq" api must work ok

Comment: @Anders - of course i can check under debugger single or both binary versions, compare parameters and structure and say exactly where problem. but for this need have binary . *How is it possible for VCx86 to work but MinGWx86 to fail?* - this mean some different code generated. may be for `FILE_RENAME_INFORMATION` layout.. hard say without view exactly binary code

Comment: @RbMm

I have uploaded the mingw_x86 binary and the vs_x86 binary in this github repo as well as comments about how i compiled each: https://github.com/Octoberfest7/Delete-self-files 

As a reminder, the mingw_x86 succeeds when run as an admin, however fails when run as a normal user

Comment: @Octoberfest7 - ok, i look for this

Comment: @Octoberfest7 - but you not use my code and wrong allocate and fill `ds_rename_handle`. the `FileNameLength` hardcoded to 4 - so this is 2 chars - `:w` only.

Comment: @RbMm Yes I understand.  I implemented your code in what will be the production version and it indeed solves the memory issues.  What i uploaded to github is the original code from the POC, as the author asked for the binaries as you did.  After I implemented your code in order to fix this issue, I received the 0xc0000033 error.  This suggests that the MingW error exists even when the memory issues are fixed.  I also tried your code snippet without the NT function which again fixed the memory issues, however did not resolve the MingW issue

Comment: @Octoberfest7 - yes, i view 0xc0000033 error. 15 min - i say src of error

Comment: I was only able to figure out using the NT snippet you provided in MingW, as I was having issues getting the WDK and associated header files for use in VS.  So I cannot even provide a VS version of the code using your NT function for comparison.  I figured that given we know that the issue exists in the code both before and after the memory issue has been resolved, you might be able to do the comparison with the original POC.

Comment: @Octoberfest7 - yes, very interesting - different result for vs_x86.exe and mingw_x86.exe when run without admin. parameters the same. some different in kernel. need more time for look

Comment: @RbMm I appreciate you looking into it and will be checking back hoping for updates!

Comment: @Octoberfest7 - this is really interesing case and in user mode no diferent between mingw_x86.exe and vs_x86.exe - parameters in nt call the same. despite name is `:w` really - this not important here. with admin privilege all work. but without it fail only mingw_x86.exe. until i looking

Comment: Trying this on Win8 now with the same result. SetFileInformationByHandle calls kernelbase!Win32Rename which creates its own FILE_RENAME_INFORMATION and memcpy's the filename and this is always `3a 00 77 00 0d f0 ad ba-ab ab ab ab ab ab ab ab  :.w.............` (not that the suffix bytes matter) when it calls NtSetInformationFile (vc and mingw). And I tried a much older vc version and it fails like mingw (and also fails on 32-bit Windows). The working vc exe has a manifest and loadconfig, could this be a clue?

Comment: @Anders - need look inside kernel. probably in ntfs!NtfsStreamRename in kernel debugger. until can not say in what problem, but really related to elevated/not elevated token

Comment: @RbMm If it is token related, why would the vc version work non-elevated?

Comment: @Anders - until i research problem under debugger. can not say just now, need some time. i will write when understand all details exactly :) until only view that request even not reach ntfs!NtfsSetRenameInfo .. so faster fail inside I/O manager

Comment: The manifest makes it work/not work.

Comment: @Anders - probably. but need understand why this, and why so strange error  STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_INVALID